# ReSharper 2020.4 - How can I remove blank lines between properties

Tags: c#, resharper

I have tried everything I can think of but have still not been able to move the blank lines here.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Please note I would like ReSharper to be able to do this for hundreds of files in my project so I need to be able to set this up in the options.  However nothing I tried so far seems to work.

[image]

Comment: could you please be elaborate? does resharper block the "delete" key on your keyboard?

Comment: ReSharper 2020.4 doesn't exist yet, do you mean 2020.2.4 or 2020.3?

Comment: Please could you give the before and after states of your code. Have you taken a look at the `ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Code Editing`->`C#`->`Formatting Style`->`Blank Lines`->`Around property/event`, then do a full code clean up to apply to your whole code base - expect lots of changes when you commit it back to source control though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that Resharper blank line options (at least in c#) do not remove blank lines.  It will expand what what is set, but not reduce it to what is set.

Comment: Do you mean this to answer the question? It looks only like a "Me too" to me, which is not considered an answer here. If you cannot [edit] according to [answer] please delete this.